# PendingIntent on Notification starting a new of the same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want the `PendingIntent` set to the `Notification` not to start a new `Activity` (nor add it to the back stack) if said `Activity` is already started

I should be missing something cause I tried this [Prevent notification PendingIntent starts Activity already started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934061/prevent-notification-pendingintent-starts-activity-already-started), [Android: new Intent() starts new instance with android:launchMode="singleTop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop) and [Android notification bar open last active activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089213/android-notification-bar-open-last-active-activity) but none of them work.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

> android:launchMode="singleTop"

This only stops opening a new instance of the Activity from the same Activity. eg: Trying to open ActivityA from ActivityA.

Something like `instance1 of ActivityA -> ActivityB -> instance2 of ActivityA` will still work  with **android:launchMode="singleTop"**.

Which case are you experimenting?

also try `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and work on `onNewIntent();`