# Avoiding to launch the app again

Tags: android, launch

I've developed an app and everything is fine, but if a push the 'Home' buttom, it goes to the home screen. All right til then. But if i click on the icon to come back to the app... sometimes it comes back to the old instance of the app and sometimes it launches a new instance of the app over the old one. I don't get why or when makes every casescenario happen.

Is there any way of avoiding this and come back always to the old one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your activity launch mode to singleTop

Refer to the following answer:

[Android: new Intent() starts new instance with android:launchMode="singleTop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop/2427385#2427385)

Comment: I had been looking for a similar topic but i hadn't found it. I need to do something else but that's the hint i needed. Thanks.