# Android. How to start activity without creating new one?

Tags: java, android

I tried to set attribute `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for calling Activity, but it still does not works as I expected.

I need that method `onCreate(Bundle bundle)` to be called only once, but it still calls each time when I start Activity.

I start Activity using code like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

It must be like this:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

and calling:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Already existed topic about this: [Android: new Intent() starts new instance with android:launchMode="singleTop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you make your launch mode 'singleTop', a new activity will be started.

At *each* activity creation, its `onCreate()` will be started.

My understanding is that the singleTop option, basically finishes the caller Activity.

I think that you may think that `onCreate()` is a form of *Application* constructor but it really is an *Activity* constructor. You may want to do your one time initializations elsewhere.