# intent extras with single top mode in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

[Android: new Intent() starts new instance with android:launchMode="singleTop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop)

i got single top to work as per the link above, but I am having a hard time putting "extras" in the intent and then performing a function on my original activity.. is this possible?

```
Intent I= new Intent(context, away.class);
I.putExtra("number",  number);
I.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |       Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

this snippet is from my broadcast receiver and it refers back to my main class.. in my main class my code is like so..

```
Intent I = getIntent();
int number = I.getIntExtra("number", -1);
```

so my question is the following..
how can i get my main activity to evaluate the number i send back and then fire a function when my receiver class fires it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override onNewIntent and get the extra there.

```
You have to override onNewIntent and get the extra there.  

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);


    int number = intent.getIntExtra("number", -1);
}
```

In your broadcast receiver

```
Intent I = new Intent(context, away.class);
I.putExtra("number",  number);
Log.d("here", "number = " + number);
I.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(I);
```

Comment: ok so now my app doesn't crash.. from the onNewIntent can I fire a function? i tried and it doesnt do anything..

Comment: onNewIntent is called before onResume. I do not know what function you try to call. Called it onResume.

Comment: I didnt get that far, I just tried something arbitrary like a toast to say hey.. but the thing is i thought onResume is if you leave your activity?(Btw im a web programmer and I am trying to learn java so please bear with me..)

Comment: i just added what i added to my main class

Comment: onResume mean you come back to the activity, onPause mean you are leaving. Instead of toast just put Log.d("onNewIntent", "number = " + number) and see if logcat show the right number.

Comment: But the thing is I am never leaving my activity because my other class is a broadcast receiver not an intent that I am coming back from...

Comment: Ok still you get it in onNewIntent, just log it and see what happen.

Comment: did i have to change anything in my other class?

Comment: Just set it as I.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

Comment: nope. i and  I tried to take it out all together still same thing

Comment: the number is fine though i tried to log it when i fire my intent so I am not sure whats going on.. the oN new intent is not firiing

Comment: I did not see startActivity(I) in your broadcast receiver

Comment: yes because eclipse gave me an error saying it wasnt a method of the broadcast receiver

Comment: my app actually just crashes now because it wont let me call the context from inside the broadcast receiver idk y

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) use the context parameter

Comment: I did.. eclipse logcat said that context requrire flag_activity new task flag.. i

Comment: oh jeez, how obvious they were out of order and fire sequentially. I feel like an idiot.