# Android application not exiting

Tags: android, exit, close-application

I have an activity from where on click of back button, the app should display home page, I have written a method for exiting the page as :

```
private void exitQuiz() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

In the home page again when I am pressing back button, it's not exiting the application but stays on Home activity when I press back again then only it exits the application. I further tried by adding following code to home activity to handle such scenario:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

but still it still exiting on one click of back button. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you offer more clarification?

Comment: `System.exit(0);` Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

```
private void exitQuiz() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably creating a new instance of the HomeActivity when trying to get back to it.

Check it out for a solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2427385/770467

Comment: thanks but I can't use that because there is an intermediate page between my home page and the current activity, so it will go to intermediate activity rather than home activity.

Comment: Thanks you are right I was creating a new instance.