# Android clear / finish previous activities except one

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

In android I have the following path:

Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> ... Activity N -> press button ...

When the button is pressed I want to Clear/Finish ALL activities from Activity 2 until N and then go to Acitivy X. In other words I want to finish all activities down to the initial One and then move to another.

If I use the flags:

CLEAR_TOP, CLEAR_TASK, NEW_TASK etc

theoritically it would finish ALL previous activities with the initial one. Is there any way to keep the initial one alive and move to activity X?

Comment: Hi, did you try to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT ? It will bring the running instance(if there's one) of your activity to the top of the stack, then you can clear all the orders and continue... this could be a solution don't know if it will works for you. Also, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand the question. Or rather, the reason for not being able to use  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

If I understand correctly, that's exactly what you want. In particular for,

> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> ... Activity N -> press
>   button ...

Launching an Intent with `Activity2.class` **and** flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` would go back to the **existing** instance of Activity2 (instead of creating a new one) and deliver the new intent in `onNewIntent()`. You just need to add an extra to this intent, so that this method will know that it's supposed to call ActivityX afterwards.

That is, unless I'm missing something. :)

Comment: Hmmm. That I think is a good Idea. So I will have to start acitivity 1 with clear_top and pass an extra to tell it to move to Activity X after it starts. Although the user will have to wait for both acitivties to load. The other problem is that the first activity must know all "extras" of acitivity X and pass them back

Comment: @Panos The user won't actually have to wait for Activity1 (I thought it was 2) if you pass in single_top, the existing one will be brought back to the front. And it doesn't need to know all extras either, you can just use `intent.putExtras(src)` in `onNewIntent()` to copy them all.

Answer (score 1):

if you have already visited a actitvity and have not called `finish()` on leaving it then 
do this

```
finish();
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Create_Your_Pizza.this, MainActivity.class);
mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);;

mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(mIntent);
```