# Android: How to clear all activities in previous stack apart from the first activity

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-stack

I have list of activities stack as a form but once the form finished I wanted to clear all the stack apart from the first activity but display a new activity so when clicking back on new activity will go back to the first activity.

E.g. A -> B -> C -> D then become A -> E so the E will be visible to the user after submitting the form on D..

Do I launch in this way?

```
Intent message = new Intent();
message.setFlag(ACTIVITY_FLAG_CLEAR_TOP)
message.addClass(getContext(), E.class)
startActivity(E.class);
```

Comment: You can use Finish() method or add flags to the intents. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24524014/5577385

Comment: I think this will not work. CLEAR_TOP means that if you start A,B orC, the activities above it will be cleared. if you use finish when launch C and D, you can achieve A->E, but D can not back to C and C can not back to B. while if you do want A->B->C->D then become A->E, one possible way is use StartActivityForResult and handle the onActivityForResult in A,B,C,D and in A, you start E.

Comment: Do you mean finish every activity on each of the onActivityForResult

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct one is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you the way I do it when I want to logout from an app.

This can work for you to finish activities B -> C -> D and start activity A

First I create a logout method in a class with session details

```
public void logoutUser(){

    clearSharedPreferences();

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("com.test.your.packgage.ACTION_LOGOUT");
    _context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    // We send a broadcast to all registered activities
    // this way all activities will run finish ()
    // And they will be automatically closed
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(_context).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

}

public void clearSharedPreferences() {
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then, in every activity you have to do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.test.your.packgage.ACTION_LOGOUT");
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("onReceive","Logout in progress");

            finish();
        }
    }, intentFilter);
}
```