# How to check if intent/activity is already open in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So, I'm kind of a noob in Android but I searched a lot for this and I was not able to find a solution:

In my navigation drawer, each row opens a new intent. How can I check if a certain intent is open/active so that I'll use that instead of creating a new one?

I tried using this solution:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424488/android-new-intent-starts-new-instance-with-androidlaunchmode-singletop)

But my issue is that the drawer opens the same class everytime, but each class has different "extras." For example:

```
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        Intent intent=null;
        switch (position) {
            case 1:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ARGUMENT","SECTION 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("ARGUMENT","SECTION 2");
               break;
            case 3:
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ARGUMENT","SECTION 3");
                break;
           }        
      startActivity(intent);
    }
```

How can I check if an intent with that class and with those extras is already open?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use `shared preferences` or extent from Application class where you store last/current activity visible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shared preferences` or extent from `Application` class where you store last/current activity visible

If you extend class for Application or you are targetting devices **API Level 14 or above** you can implement [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html).

Sample Code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private static boolean isMySomeActivityVisible;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Register to be notified of activity state changes
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof YOURACTIVITY) {
             isMySomeActivityVisible = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof YOURACTIVITY) {
             isMySomeActivityVisible = false;
        }
    }

    // Other state change callback stubs
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Im going to test it now. But how about extras that I have in intents? Can I check for these here as well?

Comment: Also, Im not so sure how I can use this. Where does the checking of the "DisplayActivity" class come into play? Thanks!

Comment: You can make this singleton and call the instance when you want to check which activity is in display

Answer (score 1):

You can also check about the launch modes in android which you make use of.
I think it will serve your requirement well.
For your reference have a look at this
http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/6/16/android-understanding-activity-launchmode